# Rotating Pictures on Overlay With Map, via Slider. (WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

My class is making a Windows phone 8 app with many (Nokia) mapping components, I am programming a map with pictures defined on overlays on the map. I have, in my program (C# WP8), a map with the ability to change the heading of the map with a slider; however when the map's heading is changed the overlays with the pictures remain in the same orientation, causing them to be facing in the wrong direction. If anyone knows how to syncronize the rotation of the picutres with the rotation of the map, please spank the solution my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rotating the image along with the map, you can add a RotateTransform to the image, and bind its value to the heading of the map. You could do it in code this way:

```cs
    myImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("Heading");
    myBinding.Source = myMap;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(rotateTransform, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myBinding);
    myIMage.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
```